# Sum of Random Variables and Fourier Transform

Tags: probability, fourier-analysis

I have two dependent Random Variables, having different distribution, and I want to calculate the sum of them. To be more specific, the dependence is given by the formula: Y = a * X, where x,y are RVs and a a positive number. What is the sum of $f_X$, $f_Y$?

I want to avoid a formula with convolution, because it is difficult to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

$X+Y=aX+X=(a+1)X$, so $f_Y(x)=f_X(x/a)/a$ and $f_{X+Y}(x)=f_X(x/(a+1))/(a+1)$
$f_Y(x)dx=Pr(x<Y<x+dx)=Pr(x/a<X<x/a+dx/a)=f_X(x/a)dx/a$

Comment: Why $f_Y$(x)=$f_X$(x/a)/a holds?

Comment: To be more specific, Wiki mentions for independent RV 
$f_{U+V}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_U(y) f_V(x - y)\,dy
= \left( f_{U} * f_{V} \right) (x)$

I am searching for the respective formula, when we have U, V dependent.